# azure search index/indexer not indexing new data

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Short story:
I'm using azure search service and it looks like it is not indexing new rows added to my view (datasource points to a view).

Long story:
I have a view, created from many tables in my database. I created a datasource that points to this view. The view has many columns, relevant here are 2: Id and ChangeIndicator. The change indicator (int) has a calculated value, result of summing some values that changes in the tables using to buid the view. 
I defined an index, maped to my datasource and an indexer. The indexer populates the index (first time) correctly, it sees all the rows in my view and index the data (as far as I checked) correctly.

The issue is when I add new rows in view - those rows are not indexed.

I create the datasource, index and indexer using API calls.

The datasource is created like this:

```
{
    "name": "cs5datasource",
    "description": "Data source for cs search",
    "type": "azuresql",
    "credentials": { "connectionString" : "XXX - Connection string - XXX" },
    "container": {"name": "UserDataAggregatedView"},
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
        "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",  
        "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "ChangeIndicator" 
    }
}
```

The index is created like this:

```
{
    "name": "cs5indexer",
    "description": "Indexer service",
    "dataSourceName": "cs5datasource",
    "targetIndexName": "cs5index",
    "schedule": {"interval" : "PT5M", "startTime" : "2017-06-24T22:00:00Z"}
}
```

After adding the new rows (the one that are not indexed), if I delete the indexer and create it again, the view is indexed correctly. It seems like the issues is to detect the new rows. The added new rows are valid, no errors are generated on indexing process.

**I need a way to index new added rows to my view and a way to remove from index the deleted rows. How to do this?**

Thank you.

Later edit:
The new added rows are not indexed. 
The new row I added looks like this:

```
Id |   name   | lang  |    proffesion   | changeIndicator
26 | test_011 |  en   | history teacher |    49536867
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `changeIndicator` column in your view is likely not suited to be the high watermark column. A high water mark column should **monotonically increase for each new or updated row**; we recommend using a `rowversion` column for change tracking.

From [Capturing new, changed, and deleted rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#capturing-new-changed-and-deleted-rows):

> This policy can be used if your table or view contains a column that
>   meets the following criteria:
>
> - All inserts specify a value for the column.
> - All updates to an item
>     also change the value of the column.
> - The value of this column
>     increases with each insert or update.
> - Queries with the following WHERE
>     and ORDER BY clauses can be executed efficiently: `WHERE [High Water Mark Column] > [Current High Water Mark Value] ORDER BY [High Water Mark Column]`.

For capturing deleted rows, read the `Soft Delete Column Deletion Detection policy` section in [Connecting Azure SQL Database to Azure Search using indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers).

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I still have issues indexing new rows. When I add a new row it has a [High Water Mark Column], with a positive integer value. But it is not indexed. Only if I delete the indexer and recreate it, then the new added row is indexed. Do you have any suggestion how to fix/debug this issue?

Comment: I check it again, and changed my view deffinition so all the fields got a value (empty string, but not null) and still the same issue: new rows are not indexed!

Comment: Please read the linked article above carefully. The column values should increase with each insert or update, not just be "positive integer values". We recommend using *rowversion* data type for that column.

Also, there's no need for the view to use non-null values for all fields - the only fields that must be non-null are primary key and the high water mark column.

Comment: First of all thank you Eugene for answer. The update is working now, I followed your advice and is working fine. The left issue, for now, is that the new added rows are not indexed. I have the Id column, I have the high water mark column, but the row doesn't appear on index. The only way to add it is to delete the indexer and create it again. I'm following exactly the steps in the link you indicate: each new row has valid data. Please advice.

Comment: The fact that UPDATE works but INSERT doesn't makes me suspect that your inserts don't use a incrementing high water mark column value. 

Once gain, we strongly recommend using a column of rowversion data type as the high water mark column. Are you using rowversion data type?

Comment: Also, when debugging this type of issues, you can use Get Indexer Status API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-indexer-status) to see which high water mark ranges indexer processes during each run. 

You may also find the Reset Indexer API useful while you're experimenting with different options (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/reset-indexer)

Comment: I'm not using rowversion - the tables already exists and can't change. Each table that builds my view has a "ModifyTime" column, of type datetime. I use that column to compute a big integer representing the diff in second from that value and 1st of january 2017. I sum all the numbers I get like this, for each row. This means that I always get an positive big int, each time something is modified I get a bigger number. For update works. For new added rows the high water mark column has value, positive big int, but is not indexed. I'll try using the info in your previous comment and let you know.

Comment: The new row I added looks like this, and is not indexed:

Comment: Id |   name   | lang  |    proffesion   | changeIndicator

Comment: It looks like when you insert new rows, you need to use an appropriate ModifyTime timestamp. Also, check your logic for how you treat ModifyTime values in your view. I'm not sure SUMming those values is necessary or appropriate. If you're doing it to pick the right value when JOINing multiple rows, MAX(ModifyTime1, ModifyTime2) would probably be more appropriate.

As I've already described all the rules high water mark columns should follow, I'm going to let you figure out the appropriate schema for your view.